# Deleting and object in a polymorphic array of pointers

Tags: c++, memory-management, polymorphism

I have implemented a vector of pointers to objects. When the data types that I specify in the template are not pointers it behaves properly as a vector. I would like to use it in order to support some polymorphic objects, so the data type that I specify in the template has to be a pointer. I got stuck in a method that has to `delete` an element in the vector, and I don't know how to fix that.
I will try to make my point with this **example** that represents what I've done:

```
template<typename _Tp>
class Vector{
    private:
    _Tp ** container ; 
    size_t size ;
    size_t capacity ;
    /*...*/
    public: 
    Vector() : container (NULL) { /*...*/ }
    Vector( int capacity ) { 
        container = new _Tp* [capacity] () ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < capacity ; i++ )  
             container[i] = NULL ; 
        size = 0 ; 
        this->capacity = capacity ;
    } 

    void deleteAt ( int position ) {
     /*... Check bad position ...*/ 
     delete ( container[position] ) ; 
     /*... move data ... */
    } 

    void assignAt ( int position, const _Tp & obj ) { 
        /*... Check bad position and capacity ...*/ 
        container[position] = new _Tp ( obj ) ; 
        size++ ;
    }
    /*... more methods ...*/ 
} ;
```

**`deleteAt(int)` is called and `_Tp = SomeClass*` the destructor of SomeClass is never called**. What should I do to fix this?

---

This is the way I use the vector:

```
class Base () {/*... Astract class  ...*/ } ; 
class Derived1 () : public Base {/*... Implementation ...*/} ;
/*... More derived classes from Base ...*/

int main (void) {
    Vector<Base*> * v = new Vector<Base*> (100) ; 
    v->assignAt(50,new Derived1 ()) ; 
    v->deleteAt(50) ; 
}
```

Comment: [is_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) this will check if the template param is a pointer, it should help you

Comment: `container` should be defined as `_Tp**` rather than `Vector**` I think?

Comment: Show how you actually use this class. How do you instantiate `Vector`? If it's `Vector<SomeClass>`, then `~SomeClass` should be called. If it's `Vector<SomeBaseClass>` where `SomeBaseClass` is a public base of `SomeClass`, then make sure that `SomeBaseClass` destructor is declared virtual.

Comment: It seems you got one indirection too much anyway: From the description you'd want your internal array be of type `_Tp*`: What you currently delete is a pointer to a pointer to `SomeClass`. That clearly won't call the destructor of `SomeClass` (BTW, the identifier `_Tp` is reserved for use by the standard C++ library or the compiler; also, I assume you mean to write `_Tp = SomeClass*`).

Comment: You should be using the vector like `Vector<Base>` not `Vector<Base*>`. Or preferably use smart pointers as Mats Petersson suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code stores a pointer to an object, it is not your task (in the container) to delete the object itself. The whole point with storing a pointed-to object is that you don't want to store the object itself, but the pointer to the object. It's exactly the same thing if you have a `vector<MyClass *> v;` - you don't want the `MyClass*` that is in the vector to be destryed [or at least, if you do want it, you'll be disappointed].

Now, if the user of your `Vector` wishes for this to happen (s)he should store a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` in the container, not a basic pointer.